# How can you style an iframe as if it were a div? (with position:fixed)

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I had a `div` containing a bunch of tags with corresponding css, all of which needs to be moved into an iframe. However, when I do that, the iframe version looks different.

I have already copied the css that was applied to those parts of the parent page into the stylesheet for the iframe. However when styling the border of the `div -> iframe`, it's unclear which styles should be applied to the `body` tag of the iframe, and which styles should be applied the `iframe` tag in the parent page.

Comment: What about making the iframe a little bit bigger and putting a div inside the iframe? Have you tried a CSS reset script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give both elements the same style.

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div></div>
```

*Note:* The `frameborder` attribute is essential for IE<9 to avoid the ugly looking 3D border.

**CSS**

```
iframe,div {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle containing that code](http://jsfiddle.net/8aaCU/1/).

Comment: Applying the style only to the iframe should be enough. I'll add a display:block; though.

Comment: @LeBen I wrote this to demonstrate they can both be styled in exactly the same way. You're right though, iframes are `inline` elements by default, so `display:block`; would help.

Comment: Thanks! However, it turns out in the process of switching from jquery created divs into hardcoded iframes I made one span `<span/>` instead of `<span></span>`, and this is what caused the problem. After fixing that, the rest was easily resolvable. So false alarm.